# Why doesn't this Rails SQL query work: companies.status = 'active' AND (companies.status_override = '' OR companies.status_override = NULL)

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following full query, and it returns nothing.

```
@companies.where("(companies.status = 'active' AND (companies.status_override = '' OR companies.status_override = NULL)) OR companies.status_override = 'active'")
```

I expect that the first part `(companies.status = 'active' AND (companies.status_override = '' OR companies.status_override = NULL))` would return all items that have `status` set to 'active' and `status_override` set to nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the DB structure, the `= NULL` is a suspect. Try `IS NULL` instead.

Arithmetic comparison with NULL doesn't behave as you might expect; more details can be found in the [Mysql Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: BOOM! (i have to keep writing)

Comment: yep, that's right. [You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that there aren't any rows that satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause.  Your where clause is of the form:

```
( a AND ( b OR c ) ) OR d
```

where

```
a = companies.status = 'active'
b = companies.status_override = '' 
c = companies.status_override = NULL
d = companies.status_override = 'active'
```

So, basically, we know that there aren't any rows in the table that satisfy condition `d`.
And we know there aren't any rows that satisfy both conditions `a` and `b`.

Condition `c` is impossible; it will never be satisfied.

To test whether an expression contains a NULL, use `expr IS NULL`.  i.e.

```
companies.status_override IS NULL
```

If you aren't concerned with an index range scan operation on the status_override column (it's likely that you aren't) you can simplify a bit using the IFNULL() function...

```
(companies.status = 'active' AND IFNULL(companies.status_override,'') = '') OR companies.status_override = 'active'
```

or using the `NULLIF()` function

```
(companies.status = 'active' AND NULLIF(companies.status_override,'') IS NULL) OR companies.status_override = 'active'
```